# After deploy my react app returns an error that cannot load a js file

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

[I have an json file in the public folder, to which after starting the application I make a request to it. When I load the application from a port on which I hosted it, everything is fine, but when I change the port with some url (test.project.bg) this json file does not build or somehow does not find the way to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P5gR.png)

Comment: seams like the path may be wrong? and a html file is returned. do you build in a sub directory? what is returned if you open the url of the image directly?

Comment: When I open the path itself, the json file opens.

Comment: i think without any info about your build process, import code or anything there is no way to find the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.